# gcc to tell a register compiled from which variable

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, decompiler, binutils, readelf

I need to know from which variable is a register of a binary instruction in the obj file is compiled from.
In short: **the mapping from the register to variable for each instruction**

**Example:** suppose objdump gives a snippet of obj file as:

```
MOV R1 5        # move 5 to register R1
SW R2 SP[-20]   # store the value of R2 to address SP-20
```

How could we know that R1 stores variable, say, ***var1*** from the source code? And R2 stores ***var2***?

I searched in the documentation of **readelf**, unfortunately in vain.
(Though it can give me the line mapping between source and binary, it helps me no further)

Then I searched for some debugging options of gcc and the linker. Found some useful info, but they still dont solve my problem.
The info i found is:

- Option **-fdump-rtl-vartrack** can track all the variables and seems to be useful. But I didnt find the expected *.vartrack dump file when compiling with this option.
- Option ***fdump-rtl-vartrack-uid** shows the unique ID (DECL_UID) for each variable. But I received this error when using it: cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fdump-tree-uid"
- Option **fdump-rtl-lreg** dumps local register allocation, but I dont see how it can tell me the mapping from a reg to variable.

Does anyone have some experience or idea?

Thank you all!

hack on ...

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: @delnan : Shortly speaking I need to trace or track a variable for certain instructions. But you can do a lot more if this mapping can be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common for compiler to produce a mixed assembler/source code listing. It will show the source code it compiled and underneath it will show the generated assembler code. A quick Google gives

http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html

Comment: Thanks! I could get this information using the **line mapping** between the source code line to the binary instruction address. But I want to know the **explicit** mapping between the bin reg and the source variable.

Comment: It is tricky because say you have a line "var1=5;", you might see that the following instr compiled for it: "sw r1 sp[-20]; lw r1 sp[-24]; mov r1 5", where the first "sw" is storing the variable "var2" to stack before loading it with "var1". Thus I need to know that for that instr, the "r1" means "var2", and for the "lw" instr,  the "r1" means "var1". This information is not given by the mixed asm/source listing.

Answer (score 0):

GCC's "-fverbose-asm" option may help a little.  It annotates the compiler's output with variable names.  Unfortunately, the names are often temporaries invented by the compiler, such as "D.1234".  It can still help to give you an idea of what's going on.

Try compiling something simple and take a look:

```
gcc -g -O0 -S -fverbose-asm foo.c -o foo.s
```

The way a debugger like GDB figures out where variables are stored at a given point in your program is (for most systems) using DWARF debug information generated by the compiler and stored in the object file.  If your system is using DWARF, then **readelf** will do some very basic interpretation of this information for you.  Try this:

```
readelf --debug-dump=info foo.o
```

It's clearly not trivial to decode.  If you want to have a go, then check out the DWARF standard(s) at http://dwarfstd.org/.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can use flags:

```
gcc foo.c -da -dp -fdump-tree-all-raw-lineno
```

Where:

`-da` produce all RTL dumps

`-dp` annotate the assembler output with a comment indicating which
patterns and alternatives are used.

`-fdump-tree-all-raw-lineno` Enables showing line numbers for statements.

This will create about 167 files, each of them means different stages of GIMPLE and RTL passes, optimizations and so on.
Here is simple explanation is what's going on:

https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~uday/courses/cs715-09/gcc-rtl.pdf

Most useful dumps are:

```
foo.c.227t.optimized
foo.c.229r.expand
foo.c.259r.combine
foo.c.307r.finish
```

And several others for different purposes.